# How can I improve this blending attempt?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, blending

I'm doing a little project to learn how to Photoshop. The objective here is to take this image:

[image: original]

and add this background instead

[image: background]

This is my attempt

[image: Attempt]

The obvious issue is the little halo effect around the beanie part. I've tried playing around with the mask feathering and other options but it either creates more halo or eats into the image. The original image is very low res (65kb), so maybe I have to try to upscale it or downscale the background resolution more? What could I do to improve this - or is there really no way to perfect old pixelated images like this?

Comment: The mask is the worst part. Not just around the beanie, but the *entire* cut out. Even the bars of the lift chair are "fuzzy". For *quality* masks it, more often than not, takes *manual* painting on a mask with a brush.

Comment: I did do it manually that's the thing. The fuzzy bars are because I added a blur effect to them, as they were too sharp previously.

Comment: Metal isn't "fuzzy" in photographs. If you look at the original image.. the bars aren't "fuzzy". Making them "fuzzy" causes them to look completely unnatural. In general, you shouldn't blur things which are not naturally soft-edged.

Comment: I'll remove the effect, I just need to find some way to make the edges blend in better. Is there any feasible way to do it with this composition? I can try taking more off with a brush, but obviously some will eat into the image. I also tried using a edge refine brush in the mask filter but that didn't help much either.

Comment: Edges of hard objects **shouldn't** "blend" into anything. Hard-edged objects should remain hard-edged. If you are getting "stair-step" pixels then you simply need to feather or soften the edge. but only by 1 or 2 pixels, nothing more. This is where manually using a brush rather than any automated technique helps.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks. Here is a previous attempt where I did purely manual selection, but it just has this hard outline which contrasts the background - I'm not 100% sure how to describe it but you can see here: https://imgur.com/fGljUvt

Comment: You need to improve mask edges. That's the main aspect that's problematic. It takes practice. This edged aren't "Too sharp" they are poorly masked - leaving a pixel or two that still needs to be removed, causing them to seem out of place.

Comment: So what's the best way to go about this? I make a general outline using pentool/quick select, then create a mask, then use a brush with feathering to manually clear every pixel? Do you think I'll ever get a satisfactory result if the image is initially low-res?

Comment: You can have it as sharp if the sharpness is consistent. I lifted the resolution with Smilla Enlargener - it's free and doesn't make 1 px wide lines nor borders wider, it guesses where's a border. Higher resolution gives room to fix blurry and muddy edges. It's done here and there in the next example:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/lyb6um5tpdg355a/SkiTourist.psd?dl=0  Anyone who has watched images sees quite soon it's a composition because the sharpness is not fixed everywhere, only a few edges are cleaned.

Comment: Hey there I'm just trying to figure out what that image is. Did it process the edited image to make it higher res? Because I can definitely see the composition effect there. How does one go about fixing the sharpness to make it look more natural?

Comment: @AlexB. I lifted the pixel dimensions to 200% to get more room. Many bad edges are cleaned by pushing perfect color with the smudge tool against a selection from few pixels further. Everything cannot be sharpened because nobody can guess the right details. Check the layer structure of my PSD to see some coloring tricks. Flatten a copy and resize to 50% pixel dimensions to make those too sharp edges in line with the rest of the image. Compare the result to your own version. As You can see I reduced the colorfulness like you, but I lifted the contrast of the landscape to make the snow white.

Comment: @user287001 do you mean you take a place with good color and use the push tool in liquify towards the edges of where the pixels are sort of distorted? Also for the flatten part, take all the layers, flatten, then half the entire image in size right? Sorry a lot of this stuff is new to me!

Comment: Flatten image  is in the layers menu. It generates a single layer image. That I suggested you to test (with a copy, keep the multilayer PSD) Reduce the pixel dimensions of the flat version to 50% and compare to your version. Edge cleaning: Select an area with path or polygon lasso. Push with the smudge tool or copy with the clone brush non-dirty color towards the selection edge. The selection prevents the spreading over. Invert the selection and continue at the other side if it needs cleaning, too. The camera has made edges dirty with its sharpening shit or someone has done it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that mask isn't very good. Even despite the fact automation makes mask creation easier than it has ever been, there are probably still some skills you will need to practice. In this particular example, I feel a mix of semi-automatic methods and some manual editing of the layer mask should get better results, although fully manual methods such as using the Pen tool would probably work too.  Manual methods don't work so well when the subect gets more complex, like hair and fur.

Anyhoo . . .

Try using Photoshop's *Select> Subject* functionality to automatically select the skier, then use the Select and Mask functionality to refine the mask. Decontaminate Colours will help remove any halos. Add smoothing, add contrast to keep the edges smooth but sharp.  Forget about the chairlift bars at this stage, you can edit the mask later manually.

Example

[image]

Note: There are tools within the Select and Mask workspace which will allow you to add or remove parts of the selection. The most useful for you in this edit is probably the top one, the Quick Select tool. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you paint with the tool allows you to toggle between adding and removing from the selection.

[image]

After you've created a good layer mask, use the Polygonal Lasso tool to select the bars of the chairlift. Select the mask in the layers panel, and fill the selection with white using *Edit > Fill*. This will reveal the bars.

[image]

Here's the finished result. I'm toggling the mask so you can see it easily. It's almost perfect.

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you very much for the detailed instruction. I actually used this method to make the selection but I'm just not very accurate with it since I've only done a few of these. My previous attempt actually used the lasso tool and looked like this:  imgur.com/fGljUvt

I haven't tried decontaminate or contrast though I'll play around with those. If I do manage to get a good selection what would be the 'go-to' next steps to make it more natural? Play around with the curves, saturation, color channels?

Comment: Here's what I made with your selection:

https://imgur.com/uwq2tIH

Comment: The next step I think would be to use a colour balance adjustment layer clipped to the masked layer, to try to match the colour temperature of the background shot which is more to the blue end of the spectrum.